# visible overlay that does not interfere with usability?

Tags: javascript, html

i was wondering, if there was a way to position a div overlay (say 'overlay') above another div ('interface'), that does not block the interfaces usability (like clicking on links).

i can only think of onclick catching mouse position and relating to the interface elements...

would be grateful for any help and ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CSS3 `pointer-events:none` property to turn of interaction for a layered element that would otherwise obscure the page.

See: http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/

This is not well-supported by a large portion of browsers (i.e. IE), however.

See also this question: *[CSS `pointer-events` property alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie).*

Comment: pretty much what i was looking for, thanks. except ie9 and opera 11.01 dont support (as you said) so i just cant use it :(